# Bit vector build on a byte array - understanding the bit manipulations

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

I am reading a code where it is supposed to implement a bit vector using a `byte` array.
The idea is that the bitvector has the bit set if a number is present at the corresponding position.
E.g. if number 10 is present the bit 10 must be set etc. It is a classic concept and I get it, but I am not sure about the actual implementation.

The part I don't get is:
`bitvector [num / 8] |= 1 << (num % 8);`

Where `num` is the number to set.
If num is 10 then the second byte must be used (`num/8` ok so far) but `1 << (num % 8)` does not set the second bit of the second byte as it should. Does it?

Comment: Why don't you print out `1 << (num % 8)` and find out?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth:Now I feel like an idiot.I was too consumed thinking it is wrong to try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`10 % 8 = 2`, therefore `1 << (10 % 8) = bit 2`, or the value 4 (100 in binary)

(start counting bits from the right side of the byte, starting at zero). Very simple to verify:

```
7 -> 7 % 8 = 7, byte[0], Bit 7 (1 << 7).
8 -> 8 % 8 = 0, byte[1], Bit 0 (1 << 0).
9 -> 9 % 8 = 1, byte[1], Bit 1 (1 << 1).
10 -> 10 % 8 = 2, byte[1], Bit 2 (1 << 2).
```

Comment: `<<` is a bit shift operation. 1 << 2 is 4 (i.e. 2nd bit set).

Comment: Actually, it is the *third* bit.

Comment: Robert, it is the SECOND bit (0-based numeration, starts from 0th).

Comment: Seriously, who talks like that?  It's the *third bit over* from the right-hand side.  If you want to use zero-based notation in your conversation, you should say *bit two.*

Comment: I see now.I was thinking as the 10th bit, the actual 10 as you cound from left to right.E.g. First 8 bits and in the second byte the tenth is from left.But it is the opposite.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You're definitely right, they way you speak is correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost right: this code sets the *third* bit of the second byte. `10/8 == 1`, and `10%8 == 2`. Everything is off by one, so 10 means "bit number eleven", 1 means "second byte", hence setting the third bit of the second byte is correct for the argument of 10.

Comment: I see now.I was thinking as the 10th bit, the actual 10 as you cound from left to right.E.g. First 8 bits and in the second byte the tenth is from left.But it is the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

It does, if the "first" bit is the least-significant bit. That's a valid way of defining it. I assume you're thinking the first bit is the most-significant bit, in which case you need to shift by `(7 - (num % 8))`. You could do it that way too.